# What is correct way to assign params between two arrays in ngrx selectors

Tags: angular, css-selectors, ngrx

I'm having problems with assigning params between two arrays inside ngrx selectors.

Problem 1: If I dispatch two actions like this:

```
this.store.dispatch(new GetArray);
this.store.dispatch(new GetAssociates);
```

So my selector works fine:

```
/* array data */
export const getArray = createSelector(selectArrayFeature, (state: fromArray.State) => state.array);
/* associates data */
export const getAssociates = createSelector(selectAssociatesFeature, (state: fromAssociates.State) => state.associates);

/* mapped array */
    export const getArrayWithAssociateName = createSelector(getArray, getAssociates, (array, associates) => {
      return array.map(item => {
        const obj = associates.find(val => val.id === item.eventTypeId);
        item.name = obj ? obj.label : null;
        return item
      });
    });
```

However I have situation where "array" data already have been preloaded and selector 'getArray' already has data, in this situation I'm trying to exclude unnecessary call to api and dispatch only `this.store.dispatch(new GetAssociates), in this case my selector`getArrayWithAssociateName` returns an array without associates name.

Problem 2: associates is pretty expensive call, so if data has been received later than selector checked that, it also returns an array without mapped names.

So could somebody help me to find what i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create selector `hasAssociates` to check when to use `getArrayWithAssociateName`.

```
export const hasAssociates = createSelector(
  selectAssociatesFeature,
  (state: fromAssociates.State) => !!state.associates.length
);
```

Or validate arrays inside selector.

```
export const getArrayWithAssociateName = createSelector(
  getArray, 
  getAssociates, 
  (array, associates) => {
      if(!array.length || !associates.length) return [];
      // return mapping
    }
);
```